# Conditional "or" in Thinking Sphinx search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

Using RoR 2.3.8.

Here's my controller code:

```
class CitiesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @city = City.find(params[:id])
    @shops = Shop.search @city.name, {
      :conditions => {:country => @city.country && (:city => @city.name || :state => @city.state)},
      :page => params[:page],
      :per_page => 100
      }
  end
end
```

The `:conditions => {:country => @city.country && (:city => @city.name || :state => @city.state)}` obviously doesn't work because I am just trying to explain what I wanna achieve.

`:city` and `:state` will be columns from `Spots` table, not `Cities` table. I want results to return either one of them fulfills the condition. But have no clue how to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tass has got it right - with your TS search call, it should look something like this:

```
def show
  @city = City.find(params[:id])
  @shops = Shop.search "#{@city.name} @country #{@city.country} (@city #{@city.name} | @state #{@city.state})",
    :match_mode => :extended,
    :page       => params[:page],
    :per_page   => 100
    }
end
```

You'll note I've set the match mode - Thinking Sphinx will do this automatically if you're using the `:conditions` argument - but when constructing the query manually, you need to set it yourself.

Comment: Thanks Pat. I got this `undefined method `total_entries' for nil:NilClass` in my view when I try to show the total number of entries.

Answer (score 4):

Place your raw search to Sphinx - you should find the correct method in the TS docu. A [reference for raw search](http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-0.9.9.html#extended-syntax). You probably want something like

```
"@city_country #{@city.country} (@city_name #{@city.name} | @city_state #{@city.state})"
```

(I'm not sure how TS names the indexes. Check that.)