# Conditional "OR" in thinking sphinx search with filtering by date range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have problem with connecting conditional OR with filterint by date range.
Something like that

```
#pseudo SQL syntax
(@date_start < params[:date_to_search] < @date_end) && (@every_day==1 || @day_of_week== params[:day])
```

--

```
class OfferTime < ActiveRecord::Base
  define_index do
    indexes every_day #boolean
    indexes day_of_week #string eg. Tue, Mon etc

    has date_start #Date NOT datetime
    has date_end #Date
  end
end
```

To make conditional OR I use this solution:
[Conditional "or" in Thinking Sphinx search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624775/conditional-or-in-thinking-sphinx-search)

This works quite well.

```
(OfferTime.search "@every_day 1 | @day_of_week Tue", :match_mode => :extended).size 
# => 2
# Correct answer
```

But I don't know how to connect that with that date range

```
(@date_start < params[:date_to_search] < @date_end)
```

Example:

```
(OfferTime.search "@every_day 1 | @day_of_week Tue & @date_start < #{1.year.ago}", :match_mode => :extended).size 
# => 1
# wrong answer! should be 0!
```

Is it possible to make that with ThinkingSphinx?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly the logic you're after - is it `every day OR (day of week and date start)`, or `(every day OR day of week) AND date start`?

The latter is possible - but you'll want to filter on the attribute using the :with arguments - it should be [well-covered in the docs](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/searching.html#filters). To get a 'less than 1 year ago' filter, you'll need to use a range - from one year ago to today (or well into the future, if that's more appropriate).

If it's the former, I'm not sure if that's possible - but if it is, you'll likely need to investigate the expression syntax and Sphinx's select clause. Again, [covered a bit](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/common_issues.html#or_attributes) in the TS docs, with links to the relevant Sphinx sections.

Comment: I am after logic: `(@every_day 1 | @day_of_week #{params[:day]})` AND date range `(@date_start < #{params[:date].to_date} @date_end >#{params[:date].to_date})`. Unfortunately there is no ">" OR "<" operator in extended query syntax. So it doesn't work.